# Proof of this theorem concerning the translation of the reciprocal lattice to the real lattice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals

So, I was reading a paper concerning periodic potentials wherein they stated that for a lattice with lattice translation vectors $\vec{R_{m,n}}$ and corresponding reciprocal space vectors $\vec{k_{p,q}}$
$$\vec{R_{m,n}}=m\vec{R_1}+n\vec{R_2}\quad\forall m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\vec{k_{p,q}}=p\vec{k_1}+q\vec{k_2}\quad\forall p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$$

The relation shown below holds where $\Omega_b$ is the area of the reciprocal lattice unit cell
$$\sum_{m,n}\exp({-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{R_{m,n}}})=(2\pi)^2\Omega_b\sum_{p,q}\delta(\vec{k}-\vec{k_{p,q}})$$

Here is my attempt at proving it.
I use the Fourier nomenclature
$$\mathcal{F}(\vec{k})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(\vec{r})e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}\mathrm{d}^2\vec{r}$$
I consider a delta function train at all points $\vec{R_{m,n}}$ such that
$$f(\vec{r})=\sum_{m,n}\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{R_{m,n}})$$ 
The Fourier transform for this looks in my case like this
$$\mathcal{F}(\vec{k})=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sum_{m,n}\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{R_{m,n}})\exp({-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}})\mathrm{d}^2\vec{r}=\\
\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\sum_{m,n}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{R_{m,n}})\exp({-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}})\mathrm{d}^2\vec{r}=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\sum_{m,n}\exp{(-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{R_{m,n}})}$$
Now, I know that the transform $\mathcal{F}(\vec{k})$ should be a delta train in Fourier space, since delta trains in real space transform into delta trains in fourier space. Hence, my result would be
$$\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\sum_{m,n}\exp{(-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{R_{m,n}})}=\lambda\sum_{p,q}\delta(\vec{k}-\vec{k_{p,q}})$$
Wherein, $\lambda$ is a scaling factor, but how do I get from here to $\lambda=\Omega_b$?
Before I seem ignorant, I want to state that I am neither a physicist nor a mathematician, I am just an electrical engineer studying nano-science.